# How do you correctly load CSV file formats in Snowflake which have quote characters wrapping string fields?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a CSV file from a stage, into a table that I am creating from the file contents. I've created a file format with the type of CSV and with settings that I believe should be splitting on ',' and using '"' as a possible string field wrapping. But the fields are still being split again if the contents itself contains a ','. It seems like the field_optionally_enclosed_by arg should be handling this, but it is not.

Here is my file format definition:

```
create or replace file format mycsvformat
    type = csv
    field_delimiter = ','
    skip_header = 1
    field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
    null_if = 'NULL'
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE;
```

Here is a sample of data:

```
"ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC","ColumnD","ColumnE","ColumnF"
"01/01/2019 12:00:03 AM","",Some - Text, Some other text - 1234567890","","",Some more text"
"01/01/2019 12:00:03 AM","",Some - Text, Some other text - 1234567890","","",Some more text"
```

Here is the table create statement:

```
create or replace temp table mycsvtable as select t.$1 ColumnA, t.$2 ColumnB, t.$3 ColumnC from @myteststage/mycsvfile.csv (file_format => mycsvformat) t;
```

When I finally select all the data from the table, it ends up splitting into 7 columns with:

- 01/01/2019 12:00:03 AM
- 
- Some - Text
- Some other text - 1234567890"
- 
- 
- "Some more text"

What am I missing here? It seems like the file format I have setup should be treating the fields as whole strings and I'd assume that means not splitting the field on the ',' delimiter. But, I cannot see another file format arg to fix this here.

Edit: Expanded the sample data and added EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL to the create file format. This should fail as I expected. There are a few other variations I am seeing where even the quote character are being preserved in the output, but I'm trying to sanitize the dataset for posting.

Comment: Are you sure that sample data is correct? It looks like there are double-quotes in weird places.

Answer (score 0):

I literally cut and pasted your code and it works fine. Check that your stage creation is correct, and that you have the right file in the stage?

```
create or replace stage hilda_csv_stage;

create or replace file format testcsv1
    type = csv
    field_delimiter = ','
    skip_header = 1
    field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
    null_if = 'NULL';

put file:///tmp/x.csv @hilda_csv_stage auto_compress=true;

create or replace temp table test1 as 
select t.$1 ColumnA, t.$2 ColumnB, t.$3 ColumnC 
from @hilda_csv_stage/x.csv (file_format => testcsv1) t;

select * from test1;
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
| COLUMNA                | COLUMNB                                   | COLUMNC        |
|------------------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------|
| 01/01/2019 12:00:03 AM | Some - Text, Some other text - 1234567890 | Some more text |
| 01/01/2019 12:00:03 AM | Some - Text, Some other text - 1234567890 | Some more text |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Good point! I sanitized my dataset to post and it removed the error. I tested what you have, then made some additions to this test dataset and was able to have it fail I was seeing. I updated the dataset above with the new data that won't split correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Even trying to work it out manually, I am not sure how the data should be split up.. How about recreating the CSV file and pick another delimiter such as a pipe (|)? This perhaps reduce some of the confusion.

Otherwise, from the example you gave can you give the expected splitting output?